# How to disable slow motion effect in Mac OS X (shift key)?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, animation, desktop-effects

Mac OS X has a fantastic feature that [enables you to play window effects in slow motion](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/use-your-mac-in-slow-motion.html) by holding down the Shift key while playing the animation (like minimize, maximize, Exposé, etc...)

As a matter of fact, I don't like it! :)

How can I disable it?

Comment: Cool - didn't know about that. And +1 for asking in a positive way.

Comment: Looks like you should have just waited 8 years where it’s now disabled and people want it back on! (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303106/how-to-enable-slow-genie-effect-in-macos-10-13-high-sierra)

Answer (score 9):

Open up `Terminal.app`

Type:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder FXEnableSlowAnimation -bool false
```

If you want to go back, use:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder FXEnableSlowAnimation -bool true
```

You'll need to restart the Finder after running the command.

Comment: Sorry... it did not work. Maybe it doesn't works on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Agreed, it did not work for me when i tried to disable the slow animation for expose on snow leopard

Comment: Eh.. didn't work for me either, Lion 10.7.4

Comment: no workie, mountain lion

Comment: no workie, yosemite

Answer (score 1):

At least for me, in Yosemite 10.10.3, the following answer from our friends at Ask Different worked: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115698

---

You can disable the hotkeys for slow motion effects by following these instructions:

1. Open Terminal
2. Go to `~/Library/Preferences` by typing `cd ~/Library/Preferences`.
3. Write `open com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and press `Enter`.
4. A window similar to this will open:

[image: XCode PList Editor]

5. For items `34`, `35`, and `37`, set `enabled` to `NO`.
6. Restart your system.
7. Enjoy.

### Source

1. [MacWorld](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785)
2. [In Translation](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2013/06/04/how-to-disable-the-shift-f10-slow-motion-animation-on-os-x-and-reclaim-the-keyboard-shortcut/)