# How to disable Expose slow mode animation in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, finder, expose

[This tip](https://superuser.com/questions/121472/how-to-disable-slow-motion-effect-in-mac-os-x-shift-key) describes how to disable the "slow mode" animation for expose, which is normally performed by holding down shift when you invoke expose.

However, the fix described in that tip doesn't seem to work on Snow Leopard.

How can we disable the slow mode expose for Snow Leopard?

Comment: See my answer here in [apple.stackexchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66433/remove-shift-key-augmentation-for-mission-control-animation/115698#115698).